# Is it possible to split "administer users" permission to multiple permissions?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-permissions

Would it be possible to split the administer users permission to multiple permissions. For example, I want the user to be able to add new users and not to be able to delete any users? Is that possible? Is there a module that help achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this module helps you: https://drupal.org/project/administerusersbyrole

I never use it, but they say: **This module allows site builders to set up fine-grained permissions for allowing users to edit and delete other users — more specific than Drupal Core's all-or-nothing 'administer users' permission. It also provides and enforces a 'create users' permission.**

Regards.